# Chaining MySQL commands, Automating database import

Tags: mysql

I am currently writing a python script to automate my process for installing a new project on my server.

I simply want to be able to achieve this:

```
use database_name;
source database_file.sql
```

In one line using the:

```
mysql -e
```

switch.

pseudo code:

```
mysql -uadam -p123456 -e 'use database_name and source database_file.sql'
```

I have tried:

```
mysql -uadam -p123456 -e 'database_name < database_file.sql'
```

The above command throws a syntax error.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Ad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
mysql -uadam -p123456 database_name < database_file.sql
```

You don't need the `-e` switch to import a `.sql` file